# error while installing migration in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cmd

i have changed all the configurations in `/config/database.php` and `.env` still got the error in command promt while entering

`php artisan migrate:install`

the error is:

> [invalidArgumentException]
>
> Database [mysql] not configured

this is `.env`

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=aqk5XHULL8TZ8t6pXE43o7MBSFchfgy2

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=larashop
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCR
```

however i can create database using:

```
php artisan make:migration employees
```

Comment: Can you past data from `.env` file please (except password).

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin ok. password is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Your .env file and /config/database.php file should like be follow

**.env**

```
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_DATABASE=your_db_name
    DB_USERNAME=your_db_user_name
    DB_PASSWORD=your_password
```

**/config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'engine'    => null,
        ],
```

Try also `php artisan migrate`

Comment: I donot have database password and  left it blank in . env file others seems ok

Comment: @micky if it is ok then try to " php artisan migrate " command